# Kendo UI: Force update of ViewModel on KeyPress in TextBox

Tags: mvvm, binding, kendo-ui

I have a textbox field that has its value property bound to a property in my ViewModel.

The problem is that the ViewModel is by default updated on the "changed" event of the textbox (when the textbox loses its focus).

I want the ViewModel to be updated when the keypress event is executed.

I don't want to force the "changed" event in every keypress, as there is some logic in that event handler and it doesn't have to be executed for every keystroke.

Is there a way to tell Kendo to update the ViewModel without triggering the "changed" event?

I know I can just manually modify the ViewModel, but I wanted something simpler and automated.

Thanks for your answers,

- Will

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Use the data-value-update attribute.  Using the "keypress" event does not update the last character to the bound model, so use the "keyup" event instead.

```
<input id="name" type="text" 
    data-bind="value: name" data-value-update="keyup">
```

I initially tested using "keypress", but entering text "abcd" results in "abc" in the ViewModel.

Comment: Make it an answer which could stand alone, even if CodingWithSpike's answer would be deleted, as it stands it's a comment on an answer, not an answer.

Comment: Thanks, bummi.  I changed the format of my response to an answer instead.

Comment: unfortunately it does not work on their widgets (maskedtextbox, numberictextbox)

Answer (score 0):

You can add the `data-value-update` attribute to your element:

```
<input data-bind="value: someValue"
       data-value-update="keypress" />
```

Documentation is here: [Controlling When the ViewModel is Updated](http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/getting-started/framework/mvvm/bindings/value#controlling-when-the-view-model-is-updated)

Answer (score 0):

```
 <input    type="text"  data-value-update="keypress"  data-bind="value: searchBySystemValue, events: { keypress: onkeypressEvent }"/>
```

U can add function in events